# How can vectorize a function that takes two arrays as input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vectorization

Assume I have a 3D numpy array $y_{n \times m \times p}$ and a 1D numpy array$x_{p \times 1}$, I want to apply the function 'PyOLS' on each slice of $y$ (i.e., $y[i, j, :]$) and $x$. How can I vectorize this operation in Python?

The following is an example code:

```
import numpy as np
def PyOLS(xvec, yvec):
   n = xvec.shape[0]
   X = np.c_[xvec, np.ones(n)]
   betas = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(X.T, X)), np.dot(X.T, yvec))
   return betas   

n = 20
m = 20
p = 7
x = np.random.rand(n, m, p)
y = np.random.rand(p)

res = np.zeros((n, m))

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
       cx = x[i, j, :]
       b = PyOLS(cx, y)
       res[i, j] = b[0]
```

How can I vectorize the for loop above to make the code faster, since the 3D array x are very large in my work?

Comment: See [ask]. Do your own programming starting with creating a stack of matrices for X of shape (n, m, 2, p). For the ```dot()```, you should use the ```matmul()``` because it does not support stack of matrices. But I don't expect a significant gain in performance because the bottleneck is the same for both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @relent95 properly said, you can vectorize your approach using an already expanded array for `x` with the following function:

### Vectorized approach

```
def PyOLS_vectorized(x, y):
    # You could extract this out of the function if done previously
    x2 = np.ones((x.shape + (2,)))
    x2[...,0] = x

    betas = np.einsum(
        "...lk,...l",
        np.linalg.inv(np.einsum("...lk,...lm", x2, x2)),
        np.einsum("...kl,k", x2, y)
                      )
    return betas[...,0]
```

I really like to use the `einsum` function because it eases simple array calculations as I can actually see what indices are being summed (I tend to mess them up), as well as for being an (usually) efficient way to operate with arrays. If you prefer `matmul` if would be more or less the same. Even vectorized, you can see we are kind of wasting resources by computing the whole `betas` array and then just using the first element; all in all, does not seem a very elegant solution.

However, I'd like to let you know that there is an alternative way of optimizing this, and that is algebraically. **If you already know this and the question is just a purely vectorization exercise, feel free to ignore the rest of my answer** (I enjoyed worked on it anyways :) ).

### Algebraic (and vectorized) approach

Basically, it is not necessary to calculate the inverse (which is the heaviest stuff going on here I assume), because it has an analytical form in this easy case. I did some good ol' calculations with pencil and paper and got an analytical solution. Given your arrays `xvec` and `yvec` (I'll denote them `x` and `y`), your `b[0]` element can be expressed as:
[image]

where p is the size of vector y, and a, b and c are the (0,0), (0,1) and (1,0) - the matrix is symmetric-, and (1,1) elements of the `np.dot(X.T, X)` matrix, respectively. These are actually:
[image]
[image]
[image]

With this equations at hand, I came up with the following function (note this computes directly the element `b[0]` of `b`:

```
def PyOLS_algVectorized(x,y):

    a = np.einsum("...i,...i", x, x)   # shape (n,m)
    b = x.sum(-1)       #  shape (n,m)
    c = x.shape[-1]     #  p

    return (c*np.einsum("...i,i", x, y) - b*y.sum(-1)) / (a*c - b**2)
```

Now, for the comparison in computation times, I tested it for an arbitrary array `x` of shape (300, 200, 100), `y` thus being `(100,)` and got the following results:

- **Original function**: **3.15 s ± 84 ms** per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each).
- **Vectorized function**: **837 ms ± 14.3 ms** per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each).
- **Algebraically-simplified and vectorized function**: **9.74 ms ± 256 µs** per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each).

As you can see, we obtain an **improvement with respect the loopy function of 1 order of magnitude and 3 orders of magnitude**(!) using the vectorized approach and algebraically derived approach, respectively. I think the vectorized functions will work for any shape array of `x` given that the last dimension matches for both `x` and `y`. Note that the vectorized approaches requires more memory, so if your arrays are extremely huge and your system's RAM can't hold the arrays, perhaps you should try Numba and keep the loopy version!